# How to develop an interface application to support the Call Control functionality with my USB headset for Circuit Client?

Tags: circuit-sdk

I want to write an interface application to support the call control functionality with my USB headset for Circuit Desktop Client.
The communication between the interface application and the USB headset is based on the USB-HID (telephony) profile.
But I don't known that how to communication between the interface application and the Circuit Desktop Client, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Circuit provides a JS SDK, iOS SDK and REST API. Only the JS SDK provides some third party call control. There is no USB or USB-HID SDK/interface in Circuit. The USB headsets supported by the Circuit webclient and Circuit Desktop App are built-in integrations. See https://www.circuit.com/unifyportalfaqlist?category=112613 for more information on these devices.